# SSRS - Hidden columns cause extra blank page

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I've gone through all the normal troubleshooting steps to figure out why I am getting an extra blank page in PDF and page layout rendering.  The report has a lot of elements, so I started deleting them.

The item causing the problem is a tablix with 4 columns that are hidden by default.  Due to that, the body of the report+margins is wider than the page width.  I verified that those columns were the issue by deleting them temporarily. No blank page.

The question is, how do I fix this since the body width cannot be dynamic?

I have consumecontainerwhitespace set to true.

Link to pared down xml: [Report XML](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8ne05EEMToieXhRMzhmLS1SRms)

Comment: How are the tablix columns hidden? Are you also hiding the rows and/or changing the grouping visibility? In the past, I've found that I've had to set visibility for rows, columns and groups to false in order to not take up whitespace when exported.

Comment: They are actually collapsed by default. Hidden=true on the static Column Group for each one.  ToggleItem is another textbox.

Comment: Okay. Are you able to share the report XML definition and anonymize it to remove any sensitive data you may have included? It may help track down the problem quicker for you - as you appear to have taken the right steps to remove the whitespace.

Comment: How?  If I have to upload it and link that might be a problem. Most of those sites are blocked here.

Comment: Did you use  hidden property instead of row/columny visibility?

Comment: @user1921849 In Visual Studio, click 'View' in top toolbar and then 'View Code'. That's the XML for the report. You can paste that into your question and format it as code. It'll show us the properties you have/have not set then.

Comment: The hidden property and visibility are one in the same.  If you set the hidden property in the property list and go into column visibility it shows the same thing.

Comment: There is a 30k characer limit. My report is over 300k characters so I can't add it that way.

Comment: I eliminated all extra text boxes, 4 other tablix, and the headers and footers. Still have the issue. I linked to  the file.